# Configuration profile installed failed in iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, proxy, ios11, apn

[image]

Can anyone help me. How to set proxy in iOS device manually or using configuration profile.
As we working on enterprise application which can only accessible using SIM provided by our company. Some server can access through proxy only.
Can you guys help me out to resolve this issue.

THANKS AND REGARDS

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mdm?  We had to make a change to our mdm server when iOS 11 came out.

Check this out.  We encoded the % encoded the +'s in the payload on our mdm server and all was well.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87201

Comment: No I am not using MDM

Comment: Using Apple configurator 2 i created profile and its worked for me.
Thanks for you update